# html5 custom validation not working with angular

Tags: angularjs, html

I am using this below form:

```
<form name="signupForm" id="register-form" ng-submit="addUser(user)" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" id="reg_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+" minlength="5" maxlength="40" required>
        <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" id="reg_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required='true' minlength="3" maxlength="10" required>
        <input type="submit" id="reg_submit" class="submit-input grad-btn ln-tr" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

When there error in form, I'm setting `setCustomValidity()` on input.

```
auth.signup($scope.userData, successAuth, function (error) {
    $rootScope.error = error.error;
    console.log("error: " , $rootScope.error);

    if($rootScope.error == "user already exists"){
        var input = document.getElementById("reg_email");
        input.setCustomValidity("$rootScope.error");
    } else{
        var input = document.getElementById("reg_email");
        input.setCustomValidity("");
        angular.element('#register-modal').modal('hide');
        document.getElementById("register-form").reset();
    }
});
```

Well the modal form doesn't close because of `setCustomValidity()` but I can't the error message I set on the input field.

**Update:**

Actually it is showing the error message on second click. why?

Error messages activates on second click and even when form is valid it is showing the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it this way. Hope it helps some one.

```
auth.signup($scope.userData, successAuth, function (error) {
    $rootScope.error = error.error;
    if ($rootScope.error == "user already exists") {
        $scope.signupForm.reg_email.$setValidity("User already exists", false);
    }
});
```

Html:

```
<form novalidate>
    <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" id="reg_email" name="reg_email" required>
    <span ng-show="signupForm.reg_email.$invalid" class="custom-help-block">User already exists</span>
</form>
```

css:

```
.custom-help-block{
    color: red;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: can you add some description of what you did there?